# Only showing logging.INFO for my app and not imported modules

Tags: python, logging

```
from HeavyLoggingINFO import Client

class IBRobo:

   def __init__(self):
        hlog_client = Client()
        hlog_client.run()
        
    def run(self)
        logging.info('MY APP LOG STATEMENT')
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    robo = IBRobo(...)
    robo.run()
```

1. I have the following statement in my python code (above)
2. I have imported a 3rd party module that has a lot of logging (Way too much logging in INFO mode)
3. I would like to only stdout IBRobo INFO statements and none from HeavyLoggingINFO.Client

Questions

- **Q1: Is there a way to only log messages from a Class of my choosing; or list of Classes**
- **Q2: Is there a way to filter logging for select imported modules**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what the logger name is that `HeavyLoggingINFO.Client` uses, get the logger with that name and set its level to something higher than `INFO` (e.g. `CRITICAL`).

Comment: Is there a way to identify that using the code base/module structure? Do I have to do something like this to get the logger name? formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

Comment: @Karun yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion, I was quickly able to identify the complicit module and set the logging to CRITICAL (example below)

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logging.getLogger("ib_insync").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```